# JSP: Set character default encoding for each request/response

Tags: jsp

Is there a way to set default encoding type without the need to explicitly invoke

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

for each request/response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content type can be set in the JSP:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

It isn't usual to set the encoding on the request. It suggests a defect somewhere else in the application. But if you want to set these things explicitly and globally, use a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html).

Comment: Hmmm, implementing the Filter interface seems to fulfil the requirements. I.e. implement the interface and it`s doFilter method. Great. Thanks a lot!